# Как обвести объект по контуру?

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Добрый день. У меня есть массив с координатами контура объекта, координаты в массиве в рандомном порядке. Нужно упорядочить элементы в таком порядке, что бы при соединении точек получился замкнутый контур (не прерывная линия). Подскажите как это можно реализовать, или в каком направлении двигаться? 
Нахожу контур объекта следующим образом

```
 //FIND LEFT EDGE OF COLOR AREA
            int LFillLoc = x; //the location to check/fill on the left
            while (true)
            {
                PixelsChecked[LFillLoc, y] = true;
                LFillLoc--;                    //de-increment counter
                bool ret = CheckPixel(LFillLoc, y, imgBrush, startcolor);
                if (LFillLoc <= 0 || !ret || (PixelsChecked[LFillLoc, y]))
                    break;               //exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
            }
            LFillLoc ++;

            //FIND RIGHT EDGE OF COLOR AREA
            int RFillLoc = x; //the location to check/fill on the left
            while (true)
            {
                PixelsChecked[RFillLoc, y] = true;
                RFillLoc++;          //increment counter
                bool ret = CheckPixel(RFillLoc, y, imgBrush, startcolor);
                if (RFillLoc >= bmpsize.Width || !ret || (PixelsChecked[RFillLoc, y]))
                    break;           //exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
            }
            RFillLoc --;


            //START THE LOOP UPWARDS AND DOWNWARDS
            //ptr = (int)bmpsize.Width * (y1) + x;
            for (int i = LFillLoc; i <= RFillLoc; ++i)
            {
                //START LOOP UPWARDS
                //if we're not above the top of the bitmap and the pixel above this one is within the color tolerance
                if (y > 0 && CheckPixel(i, y - 1, imgBrush, startcolor) && !PixelsChecked[i, y - 1])
                    LinearFloodFill4(i, y - 1, bmpsize, startcolor, imgBrush);
                //START LOOP DOWNWARDS
                if (y < (bmpsize.Height - 1) && CheckPixel(i, y + 1, imgBrush, startcolor) && !PixelsChecked[i, y + 1])
                    LinearFloodFill4(i, y + 1, bmpsize, startcolor, imgBrush);

            }    

    bool CheckPixel(int x, int y, Color[] imgBrush, Color original)
    {

        int index = (int)imagerender.Size.Width * (y) + x;
        bool ret = true;
        if (30 * Math.Pow((imgBrush[index].R - original.R), 2) + 59 * Math.Pow((imgBrush[index].G - original.G), 2) + 11 * Math.Pow((imgBrush[index].B - original.B), 2) > sl)
        {
            position.Add(index); // координата контура
            ret = false;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Инструмент "Волшебная палочка" в Photoshop.

Comment: Ну, замкнутая линия получится в любом случае :) Как я понимаю, вам важнее - без самопересечений... Но! Задача неоднозначна.  Тут не порисуешь... Возьмите точки (0,0)-(0,2)-(2,2)-(3,1)-(4,2)-(6,2)-(6,0)-(0,0). Контур? Контур. Но (0,0)-(0,2)-(2,2)-(4,2)-(6,2)-(6,0)-(3,1)-(0,0) - тоже контур, но другой и при ином упорядочении... Как быть? Словом, задачу надо поставить более строго. Вас точно интересует не *[выпуклая оболочка](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/convhull/) множества точек*?

Comment: Не понял. Вам вообще плевать какой а результате получится контур, главное чтобы не было самопересечений? Или как ?В общем случае *невозможно* однозначно восстановить исходный многоугольник по случайной россыпи его вершин, за исключением случаев когда есть доп. иноврмация. Например, если известно, что многоугольник выпуклый. Но у вас в условии ничего такого не сказано. Так что же вам надо сделать.

Comment: Ым... Это каком это образом вы собираетесь к неупорядоченному набору вершин применять "инструмент 'волшебная палочка' в Photoshop"??? И при чем он тут вообще?

Comment: Если вам нужно найти контур объекта по его растровому изображению, то что тогда в вопросе делает "массив с координатами контура объекта, координаты в массиве в рандомном порядке"? Где связь?

Answer (score 6):

Если по данному набору случайно перемешанных N вершин надо построить произвольный простой N-угольник, то одно из элементарных решений задачи - это просто выбрать произвольную вершину многоугольника в качестве "центра" (вершина O), а затем выполнить радиальное заметание плоскости лучом выходящим из вершины O - как лучом радара. (Допустим, заметание выполняется в диапазоне углов [0, 360) против часовой стрелки, хотя направление и стартовый угол роли не играют.)

Первая обнаруженная нашим "лучом радара" вершина соединяется с точкой O, а остальные - с предыдущей обнаруженной вершиной. Последняя обнаруженная вершина соединяется с точкой O, тем самым замыкая многоугольник.

Если на каком-то луче радара окажется сразу несколько вершин, то их можно добавлять в порядке удаления от O или приближения к O. При этом небольшая тонкость заключается в том, что на самом первом луче нужно всегда добавлять точки в порядке удаления от О, а на самом последнем - в порядке приближения к O.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой алгоритм построит многоугольник особого класса - звездообразный (звёздчатый?) многоугольник. Внутри или на границе звездообразного многоугольника найдется точка (точки), из которой просматривается вся внутренность многоугольника.

Answer (score 1):

Уже есть возможность для UWP использовать и [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History) и [OpenCV](https://www.huber.xyz/?p=396), в том числе все функции работы с контурами доступны. 
Чтобы обвести контур (как написано в заголовке) - нужно использовать функцию `drawContours`

Описание исходной задачи не совсем соответствует заголовку, в целом задача неоднозначна, как и предложенный [AnT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182825/ant) алгоритм для ее решения (могут быть получены различные контуры при обходе луча по часовой стрелке и против).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы занимаетесь по сути обработкой изображений (а иначе откуда взялась такая задача?), имеет смысл не строить велосипед, а воспользоваться готовым и уже «взрослым» фреймворком [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). В нём есть [готовая функциональность нахождения контуров объектов](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html).

Единственная сложность: OpenCV — нативный фреймворк, так что вам понадобится либо собственный wrapper на C++/CLI, либо можно воспользоваться готовым [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial).

Comment: Да OpenCV хорошая вещь, но под uwp  Emgu CV еще нет. Сам написать я не в силах..